# Extracting PEAR Packages and use as a Standalone Scripts

Tags: php, pear

Is there a **straight forward** way to extract Pear packages and use them as stand alone Libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download them, unzip them and place them somewhere along your include_path.
If you do this you'll have to maintain dependencies and updates yourself rather than allowing the pear installer do this for you.

Comment: The `include_path` part is important. PEAR heavily relies on in for internal includes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use PEAR packages without PEAR installation. But only this packages, which has not dependencies.